# Converting RapidMiner ExampleSet attributes to a FileObject

Tags: groovy, rapidminer

I have a RapidMiner Operator that accepts a FileObject input, and I would like to send it the value of a string attribute of an ExampleSet. 
How can I do it? 
I did not find an built-in operator that does it.
Is there a Groovy script to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Your question contains too little context to really know what your issue is (a code example would help), but assuming you are asking how to convert a java.lang.String value to a java.io.File because you have a method which accepts a File as its argment:

```
def doit(File f) {
  println f.isFile()
}
```

you can get a file from a string in a number of ways in groovy:

```
String str = "myfile.txt"

doit(str as File)
doit(str.asType(File))
doit(new File(str))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was talking about. I was asking how to convert a string type attribute of a RapidMiner `ExampleSet` to a `FileObject` so I can feed it into an Operator that accepts as input `FileObject`s.

Comment: Also, the context of the question was given in the tags: rapidminer & groovy

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to convert the example set into a document and use Write Document. Groovy is of course also an option. the fileobjects are usually just wrappers around Java file objects.